# Message listener not working properly discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm making a bot, and the message listener I'm using is not picking up other people's messages:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  chnl = message.channel.name
  ts = time.time()
  athr = message.author.display_name
  st = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  
  
  with open("logs/chat.txt", "a") as text_file:
    #print(f"<{message.created_at} | {athr}> {message}", file=text_file)
    print(f"_(#{chnl}) <{st} | {athr}> {message.content}", file=text_file)
    return athr, st, message.content
  await bot.process_commands(message)
```

It seems like a simple issue, but I don't see what's wrong.

```
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
GUILD = os.getenv("DISCORD_GUILD")


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=';')
```

Comment: Can you show some more of your code? Like where you declare `bot` etc

Comment: There ya go @Chuaat

Comment: Do you have `client.run(TOKEN)` at he end?

Comment: @lolotoster yes ofc the issue is in (I think) getting the messages using that piece of code.

Comment: check your bot permission maybe